# Is the whole job restarted if one task fails

Tags: apache-flink

I have a job that has stateful operators and has also enabled checkpointing. One of the tasks of the staful operator fails due to some reason and has be restarted and recover the checkpointed state.

I would ask which of the followings is the restart behavor:

1. only the failed task is restarted and restored
2. all of the operator(contain failed task)'s tasks are restarted and restored
3. the whole job is restarted and restored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is the whole job restarted if one task fails?*

tldr: For streaming jobs the answer is usually yes, but not necessarily.

Recovery of a Flink streaming job involves rewinding the sources to the offsets recorded in a checkpoint, and resetting the state back to what it had been after having consumed only the data up to those offsets.

Restarting only the failed task would result in inconsistencies, and make it impossible to provide exactly-once semantics, unless the failed task had no dependencies on any upstream tasks, and no downstream tasks depended on it.

What Flink can do then is to restore the state and restart processing on the basis of **failover regions**, which take into account these dependencies within the job graph. In the case of a streaming job, only if the job is embarrassingly parallel is it possible to do less than a restore and restart of the entire job. So in the case of an embarrassingly parallel job, only the failed region is restored and restarted (which includes all of its subtasks from source to sink), while the other regions continue running.

This approach is used if `jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy` is set to `region`, which has been the default since Flink 1.10.

To learn more about this, see [FLIP-1: Fine Grained Recovery from Task Failures](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-1+%3A+Fine+Grained+Recovery+from+Task+Failures) and the [Apache Flink 1.9.0 Release Announcement](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/08/22/release-1.9.0.html#fine-grained-batch-recovery-flip-1), where this feature was introduced.

Comment: thanks @david-anderson for the clear answer1